# Many to many query for postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have an elementary many-to-many relation in my Postgresql DB

### Table - User

id
name
...

### Table - Chat

id
name

### Table - chatuser

id
userId
chatId

And I would like to get all chats (actually, there will be only one such chat), which will have only users, defined by their ids.

For example, I have user with id 1, user with id 2 and user with id 3. How can I get chats, which contain only these users, not less and not more. That means, that chats with only someone of these users will not be included in the result. Only chats which contain exactly these users

I understand, there`s got to be such question already, but I did not manage to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using `group by` and `having`:

```
select cu.chatid
from chatuser cu
group by cu.chatid
having sum(case when cu.userid not in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This counts the number of users that are *not* in your list.  The `= 0` says that the `chatId` has none of them.

In Postgres, you can shorten this to:

```
select cu.chatid
from chatuser cu
group by cu.chatid
having sum( (cu.userid not in (1, 2, 3))::int) = 0;
```

Comment: Let`s suppose we have only 2 users in query with ids 1 and 2 to make it easier to check. Then it works strange for case, when I have two chatuser instances like {userId: 1, chatId: 1} and {userId: 2, chatId: 2}. I would like the query to return nothing in that case, but yours returns both chats.

Comment: @Andrey . . . A chat with only one user meets the conditions specified in the question.  If you have a different question, then ask it as *another* question.

Comment: Possibly, I was not accurate enough. Tried to change my question according to the requirements.